# Bootstrap container-fluid not working for grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout, fluid-layout

The code is linked below with JSFiddle.

- The problem was when I decrease the screen size the div blocks should be in the same line with decreased width instead they are going one below the other. (once check it by increasing the screen width).
- The other one I want to highlight is that the code for showing
  ***read more*** option for text/paragraph when we decrease the block size. That is when we click on read more the block size should increase and show the remaining text. It would be very helpful if someone suggests code for this.

  The code is

```css
.center{
        float: none;
        padding:0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        
    }
    
    div.allign{
        height:170px;
        margin:15px;
        text-align:center;
                
    }
    
    div.content{
        height:200px;
        background-color:#fff;
        background-color:#F4F1EE;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid content">
            <div class="col-md-1 "></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 allign">
                <h3>Get Started</h3>
                <p>How it works?</p>
                <p>It's very easy and simple,just sign up for free and get    started with your account.
                It's easy to reserve or cancel a book from anywhere.</p>
            </div>
                
            <div class="col-md-3 allign">
                <h3>About library</h3>
                <p>location,Directions,Books info...</p>
                <p>Total books:1124<br />journals:130<br />.</p>
            </div>
                
            <div class="col-md-3 allign">
                <h3>No text books?</h3>
                <p>Dont worry here we go...</p>
                <p>Reserve your books from online by just one click.
                Read online/offline by downloading pdf files.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click here for a JSFiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/nvpqfxbj/6/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "md" grid size on those elements so they will become full width below 991px. If you want to maintain the columns on all devices, then use the "xs" columns.

Instead of 'col-md-3' and 'col-md-1' use 'col-xs-3' and 'col-xs-1'. However, you don't need the empty first column because BS address it with offsetting columns.

Also, the margins set from .allign will override the margins BS uses on the columns and you'll have problems unless you remove it. If you need the margins, use another container div nested inside the col-* containers.

**BOOTPLY EXAMPLE:** http://www.bootply.com/EfOZtUQqcs

This is the basic principle all responsive grid systems are built upon and you're going to struggle unless you understand this basic concept. It's all covered in the BS3 documentation.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

As for your "read more" problem. The code you provided is not the culprit. There is something going on server-side or JS that is causing this and you've provided no server-side or JS code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
**Bootstrap 5**

```html
<div class=".container-fluid">
```